# Ruby or Rails - Extract URL parameters from a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, url-parameters

I have this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/users?p=\x03\x01m\x88\xDB\x16X\xE0a\xA4:\x8B~Z\xA5D\xD7_J\x16\xF9xd\x83\x1E9\xC2\xD5\xAE#\xF3 \xE8\xF1\x98\x96\xA7\xAD\xE2p\xD3\xC3v6<\xDD\xBBQ*Dw(\x8DP\x81\xC6\x1Du\xA93A\xDB\xD9f\x92\xF2\xB5@\x0FAv]\xDB\x9F&O\xCB\xAAf%W\xCDd\x18\xD7x54\xDE\xAB~\xA5\bf\xB8\xF8\a3\xBE
```

I want to extract the value of p, which i'm doing with this query:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI(request.original_url).query)
```

And the answer is:

```
{"p"=>"\\x03\\x01m\\x88\\xDB\\x16X\\xE0\\xA4:\\x8B~Z\\xA5D\\xD7_J\\x16\\xF9xd\\x83\\x1E9\\xC2\\xD5\\xAE#\\xF3 \\xE8\\xF1\\x98\\x96\\xA7\\xAD\\xE2p\\xD3\\xC3v6<\\xDD\\xBBQ*Dw(\\x8DP\\x81\\xC6\\x1Du\\xA93A\\xDB\\xD9f\\x92\\xF2\\xB5@\\x0FAv]\\xDB\\x9F&O\\xCB\\xAAf%W\\xCDd\\x18\\xD7x54\\xDE\\xAB~\\xA5\\bf\\xB8\\xF8\\a3\\xBE"}
```

I'm getting \\ instead of \.
What will be the correct way to do it?

Comment: It appears that your original url contains just that, four literal characters, `\ x 0 3` instead of one escape sequence `\x03`. I'd look into how you generate the url.

Comment: url param is encrypted using ruby_rncryptor gem. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: I don't think a url string can have arbitrary binary data in it. Try [url-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your encrypted binary stream before you put it in a url.